# How to suppress sprintf() warning 'directive writing between 1 and 11 bytes into a region of size 6 '

Tags: c

I am using `sprintf()` to create a string, `literal` is an integer.

```
char tag[16];
sprintf(tag, "Literal - %d", literal);
```

But the project make is considering  all warnings as error and raising error:

```
error: ‘%d’ directive writing between 1 and 11 bytes into a region of size 6 [-Werror=format-overflow=]  
   sprintf(tag, "Literal - %d", literal);    //snprintf(tag, 16, "Literal - %d", literal);  
           ^~   
apps/ziptest/test_literals_lzma.c:42:15: note: directive argument in the range [-2147483648, 255]   sprintf(tag, "Literal - %d", literal);    //snprintf(tag, 16, "Literal
    - %d", literal);  
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~   
apps/ziptest/test_literals_lzma.c:42:2: note: ‘sprintf’ output between 12 and 22 bytes into a destination of size 16   sprintf(tag, "Literal - %d", literal);    //snprintf(tag, 16, "Literal - %d", literal);     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors Makefile:370: recipe for target
```

can this warning be avoided? (literal range is from 0 to 255)

Comment: Do you understand the problem that it's flagging?  What is the possible range of `literal`?

Comment: literal range is from 0 to 255,

Comment: maybe declare `literal` as `short` if it's not too big

Comment: try this: `sprintf(tag, "Literal - %hd", (short)literal); `

Comment: Lesson -- Don't skimp on buffer size...

Comment: Post the type of `Literal`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

with

```
sprintf(tag, "Literal - %d", literal);
```

since your buffer is 16 bytes, and the prefix is 10 bytes, that leaves 5 bytes to write the string representation of `literal`.

Since `int` is probably 32 bit on your system, it ranges up to 2147483647 and negative-wise -2147483648 (11 characters), the compiler warns you (since it was able to compute all the sizes)

Now since you know that the range cannot be outside 0-255, just reduce `literal` size by, for instance, declaring it as `unsigned short` (`short` can be 6 bytes long as a string: `-32768` as chux noted in comments) so you have leeway for your value.

```
unsigned short literal = 123;
sprintf(tag, "Literal - %hu", literal);
```

(you could use `unsigned char` which ranges exactly from 0 to 255, using `%hhu` format specifier)

or just cast when printing:

```
sprintf(tag, "Literal - %hu", (unsigned short)literal);
```

(`%u` probably works too, but depends on how smart the compiler is: is it analysing just the format or the size of variable args?)

Let's not forget the most obvious solution now that we know why the warning occurs: let's define the array with a large enough size.

```
char tag[25];  // 21 would have been okay
```

should do it. Shaving it too close isn't generally a good idea, unless you're running out of ressources.

Comment: The cast is the least invasive change.

Comment: `literal = SHRT_MIN; sprintf(tag, "Literal - %d", (short)literal);` needs a at least a 17 `char` array for the string.  So like problem as `sprintf(tag, "Literal - %d", literal);`

Comment: @chux I didn't check that. I didn't want to go into "unsigned char" area. But I supposed that the warning would still occur, and if it doesn't, well, good. I have edited my answer. I don't like unsigned, but if OP wants to maintain the length of 16 for his array, there's no choice.

Comment: An alternate choice, among many, include: `sprintf(tag, "Literal - %d", literal%256);` to limit decimal text to 4 characters.

Comment: yes, if the compiler is smart enough to see that limit. I couldn't reproduce the warning with the last gcc, so maybe it's clang, which has even better warnings.

Comment: I like chux solution where the literal is bitwise anded (%) with a known value. However, I think that sprintf(tag, "Literal - %d", literal%256) should actually be sprintf(tag, "Literal - %d", literal%255) because 256 is 100000000 and 255 is 11111111.  I was looking for a solution to this same issue when trying to sprintf hours and minutes into a 9 byte string and this was the only way I was able to make the compiler shut up about it.  Here is my method call: if (this->hour > 12) sprintf(tmp, "%02d:%02d PM", (this->hour-12)%15,this->min);

Answer (score 4):

This warning is valid because `tag` is not large enough to hold all possible values of the string to be constructed.

An integer, assuming 32 bits, needs up to 11 characters to store its string representation.  There are 10 characters written to `tag` before the integer value, so there are 6 bytes left to write other data.  That's what the warning is telling you.

Since `literal` has a range of 0 to 255, you can cast the value to `unsigned char` and use `%hhu` for the format specifier, which states that the argument is an `unsigned char`.

Comment: One doubt, assuming a 32 bit integer wouldnt it need 4 bytes of space than 11?

Comment: @AamirShaikh As number, it takes four bytes.  As the *string representation* of a number, it takes 11, e.g. -2000000000.  Each character printed takes up a byte.

Answer (score 2):

In general `sprintf` is considered unsafe, as it doesn't check the bounds of its ouput array.  You should consider using `snprintf` instead when writing into a fixed size buffer.  You could also check the return value to see if the buffer was too small

```
if (snprintf(tag, sizeof(tag), "Literal - %d", literal) >= sizeof(tag))
    fprintf(stderr, "tag buffer overflow -- string is truncated\n");
```

Comment: And also make sure the buffer is big enough that it will hold the output from any input.

Comment: @chris This trades one problem (buffer overflow) for another (incomplete text in `tag`).  Proper use of `snprintf()` obliges checking its return value - so far not done here.

Comment: The point of this warning is that it actually makes the use of sprintf() safe as long as the code is warning free.

Answer (score 0):

As a addition to other answers -- from the warning message, it looks like you've already provided an upper bound of 255 on `literal`, but no lower bound.  Perhaps you have an `if (literal >= 256)` that causes this code to not be reached?  If you also provide a lower bound (perhaps make the check `if (literal < 0 || literal >= 256)`) then the warning should go away.

More generally, though you don't show enough context in this code to know what is really going on, this kind of warning comes from the compiler trying to make sure you sanitize input from the user, checking to make sure that it is reasonable before doing something with it that might cause undefined behavior if it is unreasonable.  So the warning is an indication that your input error checking is inadequate.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix:

```
sprintf(tag, "Literal - %d", literal & 0xff);
```

This works, because the compiler is smart enough to see that the arg range is properly limited with the bitwise operation.