# 'sprintf' output between 9 and 12 bytes into a destination of size 9

Tags: c, printf

I have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697753/how-to-suppress-sprintf-warning-directive-writing-between-1-and-11-bytes-into) issue, but i cannot figure out how it applies in my case.

While using

```
  char time[9];

  sprintf(time, "%2d:%2d:%2d",
          timestamp.Hour(),
          timestamp.Minute(),
          timestamp.Second());
```

i get the warning 
`'sprintf' output between 9 and 12 bytes into a destination of size 9`
and

randomly reboot's at the micro-controller running the code (if they are somehow related).

So, where these extra 3 bytes came from? How can i fix this one?

The Hour(), Minute() & Second() methods, actually return `uint8_t`

Comment: The '2' in the format string is a minimum field with, not a maximum.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is the king of this issue.  He was asking about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780368/how-to-stop-gcc-complaining-about-directive-output-may-be-truncated-in-snprint), and it came up again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57936803/gcc-warning-me-about-directive-output-truncation).

Comment: I expect `if (t.hour > 23 || t.minute > 59 || t.second > 59, 0) __builtin_unreachable();` or `assert(t.hour <= 23 && t.minute <= 59 && t.second <= 59);` to work as they have always worked to suppress warnings, but it looks like there are some bugs in `-Wformat-overflow` implementation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your compiler apparently knows that a `uint8_t` value can result in 1 to 3 digits, but not that the `Hour`, `Minute`, and `Second` functions can only return up to 2-digit values.

If you passed the value `255` with a `"%2d"` format, you'd get 3 characters. If all three arguments are 100 or greater, you'd write 12 bytes into the destination array. The compiler is warning you about an error that could theoretically occur given the types of the arguments, but presumably can't happen given the actual values being passed. (I'm somewhat impressed that it was able to give this warning, and not surprised that it doesn't know about the semantics of those functions.)

The reboot is probably unrelated. Try examining the contents of `time` after the `sprintf` call. I think you'll find that the problem isn't occurring there, and the warning is spurious. You could silence the warning by defining `char time[12];`, or you could just ignore the warning.

This diagnostic is produced by gcc with the option `-Wformat-overflow=2`, [documented here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Comment: I'm impressed, too, although this is not the first time it's come up: see the links in the comment I posted on the question.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously any properly written function to return hours, minutes and seconds (relative to the current minute) will return a maximum two-digit value, but you can't expect your compiler or analyzer to know that. It's the size of the *type being returned from the function* that is taken into account. The maximum number of characters in a base-10 representation of an 8-bit number is 3 (or 4 if it's signed and negative).

Also, the '2' in your format string indicates the minimum number of characters to be printed, not the maximum.

I would recommend increasing the buffer size to accommodate this unless you are really tight for space on your target platform.

If you can't get bigger than 9 bytes, try this:

```
char time[9];

sprintf(time, "%2d:%2d:%2d",
      min(timestamp.Hour(), 23),
      min(timestamp.Minute(), 59),
      min(timestamp.Second(), 59));
```